# Laravel : Empty results with raw query with binding parameters

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent, binding

I need to fetch some data in laravel using a secondary connection database in SQL Server.

My code is this:

```
        DB::connection('sqlsrv')->enableQueryLog();
        $clstamp = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
                    ->table('cl')
                    ->select('clstamp','ncont','no')
                    ->where("ncont", "507751167")
                    ->get();

        dd(DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getQueryLog(),$clstamp );
```

The result is:

[image: result of this code]

When I remove the "->where" line, my data appears. I'm certain that my SQL query is allright, I tried in SQL Server Management Studio.

What am I doing wrong? 
What is the best method to create queries and bindings, with a model that is not controlled my laravel structure/migrations ? this SQL Server database is external i only need to fetch data .

My simple model:

```
class PHC_cl extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection= 'sqlsrv';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'clstamp';
    protected $table = 'cl';
}
```

If i remove the ->where() line, it outputs data ok - array->663 itens
[data ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwyu3.png)

I allready tried with whereRaw, putting the condition between '....' but always return empty.

My code for other method :

```
        DB::connection('sqlsrv')->enableQueryLog();
        $sql = "
        SELECT clstamp,ncont,no
        FROM CL
        WHERE ncont like :ncont
        ";
        $clstamp = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw($sql),[
            'ncont' => $data['nif']
        ]);
        dd(DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getQueryLog(),$clstamp );
```

My $data['nif] is '507751167' and the result is this : [result of DB:raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC47y.png)

Comment: 'where("ncont", "507751167")' in here 507751167 is this correct number you are matching?

Comment: Yes, my query works on the SQL Server....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code to :

```
   DB::connection('sqlsrv')->enableQueryLog();
    $clstamp = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
                ->table('cl')
                ->select('clstamp','ncont','no')
                ->where('ncont','=', '507751167')
                ->get();

    dd(DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getQueryLog(),$clstamp );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding an explanation about why this code works will make this a better answer.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect so no database reads.
when you using where , you should enter code like:
->where('key','oparator',value)

Comment: Allready try that... even with whereRaw and putting the whole condition between '.....'